# File download is corrupt

Tags: php

I work as a lab instructor and was trying to ensure that my students can't download their starter files early by keeping the files above the webroot and forcing them to log in (authenticated through the university's LDAP), verifies that it is past the release time then sends them the file using readfile.  Unfortunately any files I send end up corrupted.

My code is:

```
if (file_exists($path)) {
     //header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
     header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($path));
     //header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
     header('Expires:' . date('r', 0));
     header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
     //header('Pragma: public');
     header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
     //ob_clean();
     //flush();
     readfile($path);
     exit(0);
 }
```

I even tried sending just plain text which also didn't transfer correctly, just ended up with gibberish.

---

Edit:

Sorry I was remiss in specifying what I have already tried.  I did try sending a simple text file (trying to examine a pdf in notepad looking for PHP warnings is a bit much).

I sent a file with only the contents `This is plain text` and the result was pure gibberish.  Mostly non-printable characters.  `1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 0b c9 c8 2c 56 00 a2 82 9c 00`

---

Update:

Disabled the gzipping on one of the servers and the files were still corrupted.  removed the `ob_clean(); flush()` and the text files started coming through cleanly (can't believe enerything you read on the internet :/ ).

Zip files were still corrupted but my PDFs were now readable.  Did some more looking and it appears that there is an extra newline being added at the very start of the file.  Looking back at the text file it does have an extra newline at the front and the last character is missing.  As expected adding `+1` to the Content-Length header lets the last character come through, still looking for where the prepended newline is coming from.  Also, if I comment out the `readfile` I get a file with only CRLF (`0d0a`) in it.

The framework normally 'wraps' the content from the controller with a view and then a layout but both are set to blank files and the head controller is checking that they are blank and then skipping the line to echo the generated HTML.  Even then the `exit(0)` should ensure that only destructors get called after the transfer.  I verified this by putting echo statements in the layout and view and increasing the content size accordingly and that text isn't ending up in the downloaded file so I'm relatively certain that the newline isn't coming from there.

Comment: Have you done a byte-by-byte comparison of the downloaded file to the original to see what's happening to it make it corrupt? Could be some PHP warnings/errors being output into the start of the file.

Comment: Post resulting file contents here, please. Try with a simple one-line txt file

Comment: `Content-Description:` is a meaningless (non-standard) header - remove it. `Content-Transfer-Encoding:` is also meaningless in the header of an HTTP request - remove it. The `Pragma:` header is not use for cache control in HTTP/1.1 (which, these days, you can reasonably assume all your clients will be using) - remove it. The `Expires:` header should contain an RFC 1123 format (`date('r', 0);` will do). I recommend you ensure that no PHP errors are being generated, and after that verify that the content is not being partially gzipped by PHP, the explanation of which is too long for this comment

Comment: @DaveRandom: Made the suggested changes and there is no difference, exact same gibberish for my test text file.  Researching the gzip issue most search results point to this being a server config issue not a language issue.  Is that correct?

Comment: `1f 8b 08` is typical for start of gzipped content. Apparently your server is implicitly gzipping HTTP response. I only get a slightly different byte sequence than you get for the string `This is plain text`: `1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0b c9 c8 2c 56 00 a2 82 9c c4 cc 3c 85 92 d4 8a 12 00 5c 0c b8 a8 12 00 00 00`.

Comment: What is the flush() for?
Is there an ob_start() call somewhere?

Please post _complete_ code.

Comment: @BalusC: Guess I'll have to wait for the server admin to get back from lunch and ask him about that.

Comment: @Matt It is possible to configure PHP to handle the gziping. I have had a problem very similar to this when [`zlib.output_compression`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zlib.configuration.php#ini.zlib.output-compression) was enabled, or [`output_handler`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-handler) was configured to use [`ob_gzhandler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php) - I forget exactly which it was, check both.

Comment: @Tyler Eaves: This is the complete code not counting the framework I'm using.  I can't seem to find the link now but the `ob_clean(); flush();` was suggested in a blog post as a way to force the headers to be sent in case the server was doing its own buffering.

Comment: @DaveRandom: Checking `php -i` if find `zlib.output_compression => Off => Off` and `output_handler => no value => no value` so that doesn't appear to be it.

Comment: The setting should be sought in the server config, not in the PHP config. But on the other hand, I wonder why the client wasn't able to decompress it. How exactly are you downloading the file? By a normal webbrowser?

Comment: I was just talking to a co-worker about the issue.  My site is hosted on an internal 'test' server which has the newest version of php but isn't available from outside the firewall.  To make it visible outside we set up a reverse proxy from the normal server to this location.  We think it might be getting double, gzipped.  Once from the source and once from the middle-man server.

Comment: @Matt to test the theory try sending a request with no `Accept-Encoding:` header

Comment: Found the solution to the last problem (the extra newlines).  The authentication library had a closing tag and a newline at the end.

Comment: Glad to hear you've solved your problem. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the PHP script does not contain empty lines out of `<?php ?>` tags. In general, ensure no other stuff is echoed, but the file.

It would be *very* helpful if you post resulting file contents here, please. Try with a simple one-line *text* file.

Comment: I tested it with a text file with the contents `This is plain text` hoping to find extra data and all I got was gibberish, mostly non-printable characters.

Comment: Ok, this is no good. Please create a SSCTE (without the authentication part, i.e. no security checks), ensure it has the defect, and post it in a pastebin. I'll test it for you in my machine. :)