# PHP download is showing gibbrish on output screen

Tags: php, excel, file, download

> File download code for PHP is showing gibbrish on the screen rather than opening a save/open window. I got this code from PHP.net site http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.readfile.php, please help what should i do?

$file1 = 'DataUpload.xls'

```
if (file_exists($file1)) {
      header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
      header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file1));
      header('Expires: 0');
      header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
      header('Pragma: public');
      header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file1));
      ob_clean();
      flush();
      readfile($file1);
      exit;
    }
```

Output on the screen:
��������>������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������ f2�ɀ����\p B�a�=���=��G9!8X@�"��1���Calibri1���Calibri1���Calibri1���Calibri1����Arial1���Calibri1� ��Calibri1���Calibri1�4��Calibri1� ��Calibri1���Calibri1���Calibri1,8��Calibri18��Calibri1�8��Calibri1�>��Calibri1�4��Calibri1�<��Calibri1�?��Calibri1h8��Cambria1���Calibri1� ��Calibri1���Calibri1h8��Cambria1,8��Calibri18��Calibri1�8��Calibri1���Calibri1���Calibri1�<��Calibri1�>��Calibri1�?��Calibri1�4��Calibri1�4��Calibri1� ��Calibri1� ��Calibri1���Calibri1���Calibri1� ��Calibri1���Calibri1� ��Calibri"$"#,##0_);("$"#,##0)!"$"#,##0_);[Red]("$"#,##0)""$"#,##0.00_);("$"#,##0.00)'""$"#,##0.00_);[Red]("$"#,##0.00)7*2_("$"* #,##0_);*("$"* (#,##0);*("$"* "-"*);*(@*).))*(* #,##0_);*(* (#,##0);*(* "-"*);*(@*)?,:*("$"* #,##0.00_);*("$"* (#,##0.00);*("$"* "-"??*);*(@*)6+1*(* #,##0.00_);*(* (#,##0.00);*(* "-"??*);*(@_)��� � ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� � � ��� �� ��� ���� �� ��� ����� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �.��� �� ��� ����� �� ��� �/��� �� ��� ����� �� ��� ����� �� ��� ����� �� ��� �.��� �� ��� ����� �� ��� ���'�� �� ��� �� �'�� �� ��� ���'�� �� ��� ���'�� �� ��� ��'�� �� ��� �1�'�� �� ��� ���'�� �� ��� �>�'�� �� ��� � �'�� �� ��� �� �'�� �� ��� ��'�� �� ��� �1�'�� �� ��� �5��� �� ��� ���!�� ���� � �� �����#�� �ff��� � �� �ff����+�� �� �)�� �� �,�� �� �*�� �� �%�� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �� ��� �P� � �� �P� ��� �P� ��� �P� ��� � � ��� � � ��� �� ��� �� ��� ���� ��� ���/�"�� �`� ��� �`� ��� �� ��� �+ ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� �� ��� ����� �� � �� ���� ��� ����� �� �� � �� �� � �� �� � �� �� � �� �� � �� �� ��� ��

Comment: This is correct behaviour. `readfile()` outputs the files contents to the output buffer. As your file is an Excel5 binary format, it will output the gibberish you see above as it would if you opened the .xls file in a text editor. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Change the mimetype to the correct value for the file you're downloading.

Comment: @leemo iam trying to open/save this file to user local system, but if I remove read($file1) iam not getting any output.

Comment: @MikeW what should I change for the value, can you give a example.

Comment: The complete list of mime types is maintained by IANA [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml). Find the one thta matches your file.

Comment: @MikeW I have included IANA, same issue getting output as gibbrish.. will it be something because of memory problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
$file1 = 'DataUpload.xls';

    header('Pragma: public');   // required
    header('Expires: 0');       // no cache
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Cache-Control: private',false);
    header('Content-Type:application/force-download');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file1).'"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file1));    // provide file size
    header('Connection: close');
    readfile($file1);       
    exit();
```

Comment: I have changed the code still getting same result as gibbrish.

Comment: is there a reason it can be because of firefox or memory issue?

Comment: It is working exactly as written on my server. I am using FireFox latest. Try clearing your cache, closing all instances of FF and reopen. This is good code.

Comment: I have restarted the server and machine and cleared tmp files from the machine, still no go, same issue.. I am running it on xampp server any issue with that?

Comment: turn on error reporting and see if any errors are being thrown such as headers already sent. You may have a leading or trailing space somewhere before the headers are sent. Also, I do not see a semicolon after $file1 = 'DataUpload.xls'

Comment: hmm its works for you not sure what is the reason.. I have turned on error reporting doesn't see a error, and semicolon was already added.. its showing the content of the file on the output screen as gibbrish, that means its reading the file but showing it as gibbrish..

Comment: Its working now, i have kept the download code on a separate php file, not on the same file while has other codes in it, this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355891/file-download-is-corrupt) gave me a idea.. thanks for your help!!@Len_D